# In ProviderRepository.php line 208: Class 'InfyOm\GeneratorBuilder\GeneratorBuilderServiceProvider' not found

Tags: laravel, cmd

I m have this issue on my cmd
In ProviderRepository.php line 208:

Class 'InfyOm\GeneratorBuilder\GeneratorBuilderServiceProvider' not found

Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1

please help with this error how can i get this right

thanks

Comment: Try running `composer dump-autoload` and running again

Comment: yes i tried didn't work

Comment: $ composer dump-autoload
Generating optimized autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi

Comment: In ProviderRepository.php line 208:

  Class 'Prettus\Repository\Providers\RepositoryServiceProvider' not found


Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1

Comment: How about if you delete `vendor` and run `composer install` again

Comment: i tried it  already didn't work out as well

Comment: These two classes are cnflecting with each other is there any alternative i can use its from infyom.com

add Service provers
        Laracasts\Flash\FlashServiceProvider::class,
        Prettus\Repository\Providers\RepositoryServiceProvider::class,
        \InfyOm\Generator\InfyOmGeneratorServiceProvider::class,
        \InfyOm\AdminLTETemplates\AdminLTETemplatesServiceProvider::class,

Class Aliases

'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
        'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
        'Flash' => Laracasts\Flash\Flash::class,